# How can I stop execution of application, clear out everything, then start again?

Tags: java

I am having trouble with variables which are declared in my "UserData.java" class. I am holding all the information which were input by the user in the graphical interface there.

Some of the code in my UserData class, for example:

```
public static String location;
public static Position[] mainPath = new Position[150];
public static boolean hopping = false;
public static List<String> typicalCountries = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The problem I'm having here, is the fact that my application is running within another application, and I need to be able to stop execution of my application, and start it over again at any time, with my variables being cleared out and created once again.

I am looking for optimal solution for this problem, I have about 60 lines of code in UserData, and I need to clear or set to null every single one of them at the beginning of execution (or the end).
Note:I want to Stop my application completely, and starting it again from the very beginning.

So far, I've tried doing for example

```
UserData.mainPath = null;
```

But it seems not to be the solution I need, since it would look aesthetically displeasing to see 50 lines of code of me setting things to null.

How would I go about doing this? Any information or links are appreciated.

Comment: I have to admit, when I read a title like that I'm expecting someone asking about "how can I retain the values across executions" not "how can i stop execution, clear out everything, then start again"

Comment: Yeah, I have to admit it looks pretty confusing now that I look at it, I'll edit it now ^^

Comment: Also, just to be clear, are we just talking about pausing/unpausing an application? Or are we talking about stopping completely and starting up your application from the beginning?

Comment: Stopping completely my application, and starting it again from the very beginning.

Comment: Then my follow-up question would be "what's currently wrong with what you have already", since if you start it up again, it's a blank slate.

Comment: Don't make all the variables static, and don't make them public either. That's bad programming style

Comment: @Dennis Meng, I thought so as well, but it doesn't seem to be. I've started the application from "blank slate", but it had remembered the mainPath from the last execution, and many other stuff as well!

Comment: You'd have to provide a code sample; either something really bizarre happened or there's some misunderstanding.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's the only way I know of to make a class's variables visible to other classes, including my main class.

Comment: @Dennis Meng, my code has about 1.5k lines of code in total, It'd be hard for me to pick anything more, really.

Comment: Read about getter and setters: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to create new instances of your `UserData` class:

```
class App{ 
    void doStuff(){
       UserData data = new UserData();
       //do stuff with it...
       //when you need a new instance:
       data = new UserData() //data is now a brand new UserData
    }
 }
```

Comment: I am not really good at this, meh. I'm gonna add a new question here soon. My application setup looks like this: public class UserData { public static variables declared here outside any function, then } That's everything I have. I was accessing this class by UserData.variableName, how would I access it after doing it your way? I can't figure it out

Comment: @BlackDynamite why don't you start by telling us what's wrong with the first one?

Comment: I have posted the comment by accident, I just wanted to go the next line, but "Add comment" happened instead. Could you please answer my above question?

Comment: @BlackDynamite - I think I see what you're doing, and I think what you  want to do is create another class - in my example, I've called it `App`, but you should call it something else. In that class, I created an *instance* of `UserData`, which has all those variables. You can do whatever you want with that instance, then create a *new* instance (read: `= new UserData()`), you have a brand new `UserData` with default fields.

Comment: Oh yes, I just noticed that it's App instead of UserData, damn I'm blind, should have bought glasses. Thank you so much for this, amazing! I'll set your answer as The answer asap.

Comment: For some reason I can't access the new "data" I've created, what Am I not getting here? :/